# Parameters in constructor in Avalonia Window

Tags: c#, avalonia

Let's take simple window:

```cs
public partial class NewWindow : Window
    {
        public NewWindow(CustomType variableName)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //do stuff with your variable
#if DEBUG
            this.AttachDevTools();
#endif
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
        }
    }
```

When you do thing like this, application will no longer compile:
`Unable to find public constructor for type Project:Project.Views.NewWindow() Line 1, position 2`

Is there a way to bypass it? It forces me to use some ancient methods like controlling things via public static variables, which in normal scenario can be avoided by using constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You might have already found this out, but the XAML template requires a public paramterless constructor. However, that doesn't mean you can't add your own second constructor.

```
public partial class NewWindow : Window
{
    public NewWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public NewWindow(CustomType variableName)
        : this()
    {
        //do stuff with your variable
#if DEBUG
        this.AttachDevTools();
#endif
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a useful workaround